# onDestroy() getting called in case of "singleTask"?

Tags: android, back-stack

I have an application where I'm facing this issue. This is to the point version of the scenario.

I have 2 activities A and B. Both are set to `singleTask`. Whenever you instantiate a `singleTask` activity a new task is created for it.

[image]

So if i do `A -> B -> A`, `onDestroy()` of **Activity B** is getting called but according to the documentation it should create only a single instance for `singleTask` and `SingleInstance`, then why call `onDestroy()`?

Now i have two questions

1. Are Activity A and Activity B each on two separate tasks or inside a single task?
2. I wanna call `A -> B -> A` and avoid `onDestroy()` call of Activity B. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching i found the answer myself

> Are Activity A and Activity B each on two separate tasks or inside a single task?

Yes Activity A and Activity B are on two different tasks.

> I wanna call A -> B -> A and avoid onDestroy() call of Activity B. Is it possible?

Yes it's possible. By calling `finish()` in Activity A while going to Activity B it can be achieved.

**Note :** Although calling `finish()` is not a good option, it's just a workaround that suited my scenario.